# Why there is a geometrical boundary condition on the rotated phi/fibonacci spiral?

Tags: geometry, fibonacci-numbers

When you draw a Fibonacci spiral in a quantized way , or more clearly from a golden rectangle geometrical construction based on Fibonacci numbers, and select one of arc nodes extremity to be the center of a rotation, three nodes away from it the spiral create a boundary as shown on the picture ,  is there a trigonometric formula which explain that boundary condition ?
"phi-spiral"

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean: could you explain more clearly?

Comment: When you draw a Fibonacci spiral in a quantized form , or more clearly from a golden rectangle geometrical construction based on Fibonacci numbers, and select one of arc nodes to be the center of a rotation three nodes away from it the spiral create a boundary as shown on the picture , what  i want to know is : is there a formula which explain that boundary condition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third and fourth arc in your construction have centers which are aligned with the "first" point: as a consequence, a circle with center at the first point and passing through the fourth point is tangent to both arcs, giving the illusion of what you call "a defined boundary".

[image]

As a matter of fact, all arc endpoints in the spiral (blue points in diagram below) lie between exactly two arc centers (red points).

[image]

EDIT.

For a true golden spiral (red curve in diagram below), i.e. a logarithmic spiral with polar equation
$r=a e^{b\theta}$ and $b=\ln\phi/(\pi/2)$, 
this feature is lost.

The evolute (locus of centers of curvature) of a logarithmic spiral, is another logarithmic spiral with polar equation $r=ab e^{b(\pi/2+\theta)}$ (black curve below). The evolute is rotated by $\pi/2$ with respect to the original spiral: the center of curvature of a point $A$ on the red spiral is the point $C$ on the black spiral and $\angle AOC=\pi/2$, where $O$ is the coordinate center. The blue circle (center $C$ and radius $AC$) is then the osculating circle at $A$.

For a golden spiral, however, point $C$ is not on the spiral itself: point $A'$ on the red spiral is near to $C$ but the circle with center $A'$ and radius $A'C$ (dashed in the diagram) is quite different from the osculating circle.

[image]

Notice that for different values of $b$ the evolute can be the the same as the spiral itself ([see here for details](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogarithmicSpiralEvolute.html)). In that case you have exactly the feature you are looking for: every point on the spiral is the center of the osculating circle at a point which is an angle $2n\pi-\pi/2$ after it, where $n$ is an integer positive number.

Comment: Sorry for my first comment , if i am not wrong , the "first" point (number 4) is not the center of of the next arcs . It's only the center of the boundary circle.. the center of arcs is the intersection point of 4-6 line and 5-7 line

Comment: I'll add a diagram to explain better: it is not the center of the arcs, but is on the same line.

Comment: Thank you for the diagram . I wonder if there is a trigonometrical formula for that ! A formula to generalize that to an arbitrary choice of node which explain why the boundary circle occur three node away .

Comment: No need for trig formulas here: you can see from the picture that every Fibonacci point is aligned with only two arc centers: those corresponding to the third and fourth arc after that Fibonacci point.

Comment: So It's a property of the golden spiral , an alignment of the first point of the first arc with the center of the third and fourth arcs leading if the spiral is rotated from the first point to a boundary symbolized by the tangent circle between arc three and four .

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what is going on.

Comment: I'll add you response to be one of the solutions . But i think it deserves a trigonometrical formula . That would be great if someone find it . On my point of view , as we know the polar equation for the golden spiral  exp^(0.2theta) , on an arbitrary choice for the point of origin for the rotation (let say theta = x) , the same boundary representation is achieved at a position on the spiral theta = y = x+3/2pi .

Comment: See my edited answer.